# How do I make this letter in Latex?

Tags: symbols, characters

The letter right after `$\subset$`.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the math calligraphic font from `mathrsfs`. Load the package and use `\mathscr{S}`.

Comment: in preamble `\usepackage{fouriernc}`, in document `$\mathcal{S}$`

Comment: @Moriambar thanks for that link, Detexify is an incredible resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `\mathscr{S}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\{T_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathscr{S}_a$
\end{document}
```